# Run-time error '50290': Application-defined or object-defined error when opening an Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

There are tons of questions about this topic, but there isn't any effective solution.

This is my Access VBA code.

```
Dim fDialog As Object
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(3)

Dim excelPath As String
excelPath = ""

With fDialog
    .Title = "Carica da Template"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Clear

    If .Show = True Then
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            excelPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End If
End With

If Len(excelPath) = 0 Then
    GoTo Cerca_Exit
End If

Set fDialog = Nothing

Dim sql As String
sql = "DELETE FROM [Pianificazione Risorse];"
DoCmd.RunSQL sql

Dim mExcel As Object
Set mExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim mBook As Object
Set mBook = mExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelPath, readonly:=True)
mExcel.Visible = False
Dim mSheet As Object
Set mSheet = mBook.Worksheets(1)
```

I am opening a dialog to load an Excel file but I get that error at this point:

Set mBook = mExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelPath, readonly:=True)

Consider that:

- that file is closed
- there is no Excel file open
- in Task Manager there isn't any EXCEL.EXE task running

Comment: Your code works for me when opening an .xlsx file. Since you ask for a *Template*, what file type exactly are you opening?

Comment: In case it is a template on which a new workbook must be created, that's `Workbooks.Add`, not `Open`.